# Create clickable items in CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

So I'm creating a small python program that will launch other programs using the `subprocess.call()` function. I'm wondering if there is any way co create clickable boxes in the CLI to help the user know what option he/she has and make it easier to select them.

Currently im just using a `input()` functions with `if/elif/else` functions to determine what to launch. I would like to convert that into a clickable interface on the CLI so no input other than a click is required.

This is what I'm currently using. Have not been able to find any material about such a option, maybe I'm not looking hard enough.

```
import getpass
import subprocess
import os
OSPath = "/SYS64 3.7/"
full_path = os.getcwd()
CurrentPath = ""
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
answer = input("INPUT BOOT PARAMETER ")
if answer == "jdos":
    subprocess.call(["python3",dir_path + OSPath + "bootthingy.py"])
    subprocess.call(["python3",dir_path + OSPath + "jdosos.py"])
elif answer == "jdos.fboot":
    subprocess.call(["python3",full_path + OSPath + "jdosos.py"])
elif answer == "jdos.admin":
    user = getpass.getpass("username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass("password: ")
    bootcheck = 0
    with open('userpass.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            login = line.split(',')
            if login[0] == user and login[1] == password:
                subprocess.call(["python3",full_path + OSPath + "jdososadmin.py"])
                bootcheck = 1
        if bootcheck == 0:
            print("Incorrect user or password.")
elif "jdos.exp" in answer:
    subprocess.call(["python3",full_path + OSPath + "jdosexperimentail.py"])
elif answer == "cancel":
    print("")
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Instead of a user typing `jdos` into the `input()` you would have 4 clickable boxes of the 4 different options, looking something along the lines of this: `[jdos] [jdos.fboot] [jdos.admin] [jdos.exp]`, each one running the `subprocess.call()` if clicked

I've tried to use the `npyscreen` package but I haven't been able to make it work successfully

This is what it looks like when I use the supplied `npyscreen` code.

[NPYScreen code works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsPlR.png)

and this is what happens when I select a box and click OK

[Python program does not launch properly...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2T36.png)

As you can see, the program does run, it just overwrites the text at the very top, and I cannot enter anything into the `input('C:/SYS64 3.7> ')` function, which i think might be do to the `npyscreen` app not closing. Im still new to `npyscreen` and I don't know exactly how it works.

Comment: see [npyscreen](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/introduction.html) or look for `ncurses` module. See also [urwid](http://urwid.org/examples/index.html)

Comment: I've heard of that but I can't seem to get it to work in my program. maybe I'm using it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Npyscreen allows you to make console applications which you can ask the user to give you some information.

You can go on with this template I just made with using only basic methods. I recommend you to read documents of this library.

```
import npyscreen
import os
import getpass
import subprocess

class mainform(npyscreen.ActionForm):
    def create(self):
        self.OSPath = "/SYS64 3.7/"
        self.full_path = os.getcwd()
        self.CurrentPath = ""
        self.dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        opt_values = ["jdos", "jdos.fboot", "jdos.admin", "jdos.exp"]

        welcome_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxTitle, max_height = 2, editable = False, value = "Welcome. Select BOOT PARAMETER")
        self.answer = self.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne, max_height = 4, name = "Selections:", values = opt_values, scroll_exit = True)


    def on_ok(self):
        if self.answer.value[0] == 0:
            subprocess.call(["python3", self.dir_path + self.OSPath + "bootthingy.py"])
            subprocess.call(["python3", self.dir_path + self.OSPath + "jdosos.py"])
        elif self.answer.value[0] == 1:
            subprocess.call(["python3", self.full_path + self.OSPath + "jdosos.py"])
        elif self.answer.value[0] == 2:
            user = getpass.getpass("username: ")
            password = getpass.getpass("password: ")
            bootcheck = 0
            with open('userpass.txt','r') as file:
                for line in file:
                    line = line.strip('\n')
                    login = line.split(',')
                    if login[0] == user and login[1] == password:
                        subprocess.call(["python3", self.full_path + self.OSPath + "jdososadmin.py"])
                        bootcheck = 1
                if bootcheck == 0:
                    print("Incorrect user or password.")
        elif self.answer.value[0] == 3:
            subprocess.call(["python3", self.full_path + self.OSPath + "jdosexperimentail.py"])

        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

    def on_cancel(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)

#Application starts here
class App(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):

    #Defining forms.
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm('MAIN', mainform, name="name_here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App().run()
```

Comment: This does work, but now when I enter a option it will override the top text and i can't enter anything into the program, almost like it froze. Not sure if that means i need to initialize the other programs in `npyscreen` as well.

Comment: I think I couldn't understand what you mean by "enter an option it will override the top text and i can't enter anything into the program". You can add new options with adding in to list opt_values. You can also add new pages to the program.

Comment: I added some pictures to the question, that might help explain what is happening.